# Setting my curHash code to use ":" instead of "|"

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using the code below to be able to link to a specific tab on [our website](https://test.radacutlery.com/fundraising/tabs/).

As it is currently made, it allows us to link to the specific tab by adding `#member-tabs|3` to the URL, where member-tabs is the class, 3 is the tab to open, and they are separated by a "|".

**The Problem**: The symbol "|" isn't supported in many cases, including the example below. The "|" is getting changed to "#7C". How would I adapt the code to use a different separating symbol (like a colon or the and sign)?

Example: [https://test.radacutlery.com/fundraising/tabs/#member-tabs|3](https://test.radacutlery.com/fundraising/tabs/#member-tabs%7C3)

```
<script>
function _setTab() {
  // get current hash value
  var curHash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

  // only continue if hash provided and scoped to member tabs
  if (!curHash || !curHash.match('member-tabs')) {
    return false;
  }

  // split and int val tab num
  curHash = parseInt(curHash.split('|')[1]);

  // ignore if tab is current state
  if (curHash === window._tabSelected) {
    return false;
  }

  // set current tab to window
  window._tabSelected = curHash;

  // add click event to tab selected
  switch (curHash) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
      jQuery('#member-tabs .et_pb_tab_' + curHash + ' a').click();
      break;

    default:
      return false;
      break;
  }

  // scroll to tabs container
  _scrollToTabs();
}

// scroll to member tabs container with 50px offset
function _scrollToTabs() {
  var oTabs = jQuery('#member-tabs');
  if (oTabs.length > 0) {
    jQuery('html,body').animate(
      {
        scrollTop: oTabs.offset().top - 50,
      },
      1000,
    );
  }
  return false;
}

// set falsey state for tab selected on load
window._tabSelected = false;

// attach to window load because the tabs are initialized later in document
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  // check for initial hash state
  _setTab();

  // add hash change window listener
  jQuery(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    _setTab();
  });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Any character you will use will change into a code, it is called URL Encoding. Usually it is decoded automatically just like it gets encoded automatically. Look into URL encoding and URL decoding for reference. Basically you want to decode the hash in url and then split.

Comment: apply `decodeURI` on the curHash just after you read it, it will ensure that you get a decoded string

Comment: I've tried a couple things, but I'm a relative beginner. Where would I apply 'decodeURI' within the above code to get a decoded string?